# How to replace strings in a Javascript array

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, string, function

I am trying to pass the values of a Javascript array to a PHP URL through Ajax. Here is script array

```
<script>"Talent_Percentile.php?"+globalArray"</script>
```

Where `globalArray` is my Javascript array. When I alert this, I get

```
Talent_Percentile.php?eqt_param1=4.00,eqt_param2=4.00,eqt_param3=4.00
```

I know about string replace but I don't know how to use it on an array. I need an output like

```
Talent_Percentile.php?eqt_param1=4.00&eqt_param2=4.00&eqt_param3=4.00
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: which string do you want to use as array? post some codes what you've tried

Comment: Is this post all one sentence?  Wowzzz.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend encoding your array to JSON:

```
<script>
     var url = "Talent_Percentile.php?" + JSON.stringify(globalArray);
</script>
```

On the server side, use [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to decode the data.

Answer (score 1):

```
var mystring = globalArray.join("&");
var url = "Talent_Percentile.php?" + mystring;
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, to apply a function to all elements of an array you should use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
globalArray = globalArray.map(function(v) {
    return v.replace("old", "new");
});
```